Making use of a threadpool in parallel computations
I have a user-defined function (implemented as a Module) that performs parallel computations with the application of ParallelDo[]. My function is to be minimized with the help of either FindMinimum[] or NMinimize[]. As a result, my function is to be invoked multiple times during the minimization process. The question is about performance issues: does Wolfram Mathematica launch (create) threads each time my function is invoked (i.e., when ParallelDo[] runs inside my function) and then terminate these threads when ParallelDo[] is done? What I need is to have (make if possible) Wolfram Mathematica use some thread pooling mechanism, so that tasks (like my function evaluation) can be assigned to threads created once and for all and living in the pool for the entire duration of the minimization process. As far as I know, creating and terminating threads again and again badly affects the performance. I am kind of blind at this spot and need some clarifications. Thank you in advance!

I believe the answer is yes.  When you run parallel do it will launch a set of kernels and keep reusing them throughout.
